# link_to vs url_for vs path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting learn Ruby on Rails and I have some doubts.

I already see the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) but I don't understand at all the differences between:

- url_for
- link_to
- path

And how I can use / discover the paths of my application? Further, can I send a parameter in path, like:

```
<%= users_path + "/user.id/" %>
```

Is there anything like that?

Comment: Did you check this out? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`url_for` provides you the full url to the website, for example: `www.example.com/my/path` would come from something like `url_for my_path_url`.

`link_to` gives you a link to a specific **path**, for example:

```
link_to example_path,"click me"
```

would result in

```
<a href="www.example.com/my/path">click me</a>
```

You can also use this with `url_for` like this:

```
link_to url_for(my_resource_path)
```

`resource_path` is used to reference a path in your `routes.rb` file. For example, if you have

```
match '/my/:id/page' => 'my#page'
```

you could use `my_page_path(...)`.

If you need the `:id` for the path, you could pass it as in the parameters to your `resource_path` like this: `my_page_path(current_user.id)`.

In addition, you can add in other query parameters by simply appending them to the preset route parameters:

```
my_page_path(current_user.id,:hello => "world")
```

You ask about whether you can add paths to an existing path. Yes, you can, as these functions simply return strings to the caller, so for all intents and purposes you could do exactly what you wrote as long as that path conjugates with your string into a proper route.

Comment: Thanks, if you can style better your answer. Anyway I will give you the best answer, but is better if someone need help too. And Thanks, this really helped.

Comment: `In addition, you can add in other query parameters by simply appending them to the preset route parameters` this is good, I can't find API to explore the parameters of this? Even here too http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html Do you know where can I find such API doc of this path method?